# Correctly passing csrf with jQuery(formData) Laravel?

Tags: security, session, laravel, csrf

I have an upload script that has a fall back to flash which doesn't pass the session, instead i can catch session data with jQuery and in normal situations it works but as soon as I use it to grab the csrf token from the form i get the standard 500 error.

My route:
`Route::post('/upload', ['uses' => 'UploadController@do_upload','before' => 'csrf']);`

Token hidden in the form automatically:
`<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="1Xxv4RReHqPQS04d7dd4KECwahFDrBvY2SAlCT5K">`

How i am grabbing the data:

```
  $(function() {
    var token = $("[name=_token]").val();
    $('#file').uploadify({
      ..
      'debug'           : true,
      'formData'        : {'_token' : token} 
    });
  });
```

Debug window that shows the token is found:
`SWF DEBUG:                         _token=1Xxv4RReHqPQS04d7dd4KECwahFDrBvY2SAlCT5K`

But then when i submit it fails with 500 error. As soon as i remove csrf everything works as expected.

Beyond this i don't know what i can do, i am using the standard csrf filter. Any ideas?